# WSL2 export is huge - 118 GB!

Tags: command-line, 20.04, partitioning, data-recovery, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wanted to do a back up of my Ubuntu-20.04 WSL image or whatever is called and the tar file that resulted is 118 GB.

The login screen shows a Usage of 22% of 250 GB., so that would be 55GB. But still that's not 118 GB.

Does the `wsl --export` command archive the whole partition?

What could be the reason?

Comment: When you say "login screen", what are you referring to in this case?  Something in the message-of-the-day?  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds i am referring to this https://imgur.com/mCa2Nb5

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, that's the MOTD (message-of-the-day).  I don't have one myself, since I'm on another shell (Fish).  Let me see what's generating that particular size calculation and why it might be so drastically different than the `--export` size.  Can you do a `sudo du -hsx` (human-readable, summary, one-file-system) and see what that reports?

Comment: Hmm.  Okay, it's `landscape-sysinfo`.  Can you run this manually and see what it returns as well?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thank you for your replies.  "sudo do -hsx" returns "30G" .  "landscape-sysinfo" returns the same results as the image i posted yesterday 22.5 % of 250.92 GB

Comment: Ok, so I was suspecting a possible "cached" result from `landscape-sysinfo`, but that's not the case.  On 22.04, I've seen issues with it, but I couldn't reproduce those in 20.04, and neither can you, apparently.  So that's not it.  But now we have *three* different sizes, oddly.  30GB from `du`, 55GB from `landscape-sysinfo`, and 118GB from `wsl --export`.  Hmmm.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds my main goal is to start a  development environment on WSL. Because i'm a noob, i keep trying all kind of tutorials and approaches. I keep installing conda environments and then when i start vcode, that also installs all libraries on top of that. And although i am still unable to run a  jupyter notebook on WSL2 , i think i managed to make a 1TB traffic this month just with this task. WSL2 is basically  broken with systemd, because all the files that i need are there, i can see them, the network can't. So i guess there's a lot of data that WSL just can't see.

Comment: I think we can work through most of those issues, but yes, a lot of tutorials need "tweaks" for WSL.  You mention Systemd - Are you running Windows 11 with one of the new WSL releases that supports it?  That *may* have an impact on this 118GB image (but I'm not sure yet).

Comment: Curious if `tar tvf <export_file>.tar | sort -nk3 | tail -50` shows anything that might be blowing up the size.

Comment: Hello @NotTheDr01ds Sorry i reply so late. I just gave up and removed that distro and made a new one. Basically it was Anaconda bloating up. I'm going with Miniconda this time and paying more attention when installing envs. Anyway, thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: No worries - Glad you got it "resolved".  And yes, I tend to stay away from Anaconda unless absolutely necessary.  It does seem a bit "bloated".

Comment: in my case it was mostly docker images,cuda was pretty big and i also found a 10Gb yarn cache  inside the tar